# A new button called “Copy to Mobile” in the object order page to copy the home phone field(in Account Object) value into Mobile phone field value

Tags: javascript, button, custom

Created a button with Execute JavaScript and OnClick JavaScript

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Order__c)}; 
var updateRecords = [];
if (records[0] == null) {
    alert("Please select at least one record to update.");
}
else { 
for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { 
var update_Account= new sforce.SObject("Order__c"); 
update_Order.Id = records[a]; 
update_Order.Mobile__c = Account.HomePhone__c; 
updateRecords.push(update_Order);
}
result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
parent.location.href = url;
}
```

I am not able to get copy the value in `Mobile__c` value to `HomePhone`

Comment: Any reason you cannot just use a workflow rule to do this? Does it require manual intervention?

Comment: Requirement of client is to make button on the object detail page

Comment: Just because it is a requirement given to you does not mean you should not present better options. Of course you would have to know why the requirement was made.

Comment: don't you need to define update_Order before assigning the id and mobile number to it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?I think you declared update_Account and used update_order

```
var records = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Order__c)}; 
var updateRecords = [];
if (records[0] == null) {
    alert("Please select at least one record to update.");
}
else { 
    for (var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { 
    var update_Order= new sforce.SObject("Order__c"); 
    update_Order.Id = records[a]; 
    update_Order.Mobile__c = Account.HomePhone__c; 
    updateRecords.push(update_Order);
}

result = sforce.connection.update(updateRecords); 
parent.location.href = url;
}
```